# Unity 3D or other graphics libraries - How can I create a trimetric camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, 3d, camera

Recently I've been trying to create a trimetric game - much like Fallout 1 and Fallout 2.

How could I achieve the trimetric camera perspective? I've been trying in Unity3D , but there are little to no resources on how to set the camera to look like that. I've even been trying to create something from scratch with projection matrices and such (in C#) but to no avail. Are there any suggestions on how could I achieve this in Unity3D? If not, which other game engines/graphics libraries could make this easier?

EDIT: Yes, I've done research on this topic showing an answer on unity answers, but , it was not thoroughly explained and after following the "instructions" from the answer I couldn't get a trimetric camera.

Comment: What do you mean by trimetric?  To me, it looks like Fallout and Fallout 2 used an isometric (orthographic) camera.  Can you explain the difference?

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/39516/trimetric-projection.html (which I found when googling "trimetric camera" *just to learn what it was*)

Comment: @Draco18s I saw that too, however I don't quite understand what "pitching down 60 degrees and moving it 60 degrees off center" means. Not really thoroughly explained. Chris Dunaway yes there is a difference, you can look at the link Draco18s posted.

Comment: Even after trying to rotate it that way, I still don't get the trimetric view.

Comment: @JP_99 That sounds like a great way to phrase your question so it doesn't get closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about a month of research, I found how to create a fallout 1 & 2 styled trimetric camera.

http://falloutmods.wikia.com/wiki/Generating_images_in_3ds_Max

Here I could find the camera angles which create the trimetric perspective.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: Open your camera in the inspector, switch projection mode from Perspective to Orthographic. This is the type of projection that does not converge - variants are known as axonometric, isometric, trimetric, depeneding on the angle of the camera.

The rest is just getting the angle of the camera as you please

Comment: Yes, but which angles should I try? I've been playing around and got nothing close to trimetric.

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/39516/trimetric-projection.html have you looked here (answer from post above). in case this doesn't work for you, there's always custom camera matrix but its quite unintuitive

Comment: yes I looked, however when I pitched it down 60 degrees and moved it 60 degrees off center? (I presume rotate 60 deg on Y axis) I did not get the trimetric view.